# Maximization of sum of a bivariate optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Assume $f(x+y):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing and concave in the sum $z=x+y$. Observe the bivariate maximization problem
$$
\underset{x,y}{\operatorname{max}} J(x,y)=f(x+y)-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2} \tag{1}.
$$
The first-order conditions
$$
\frac{\partial J(x,y)}{\partial x}=f'(x+y)-x=0,\tag{2}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial J(x,y)}{\partial y}=f'(x+y)-y=0,\tag{3}
$$
Jointly determine the solution to this bivariate optimization problem. Moreover, from $(2)$ and $(3)$, we know that for a maximum, it must be the case that
$$x=y.\tag{4}$$ Now I am primarily interested in the sum $z$. Adding the two first-order conditions gives an optimality condition for $z$ as
$$
f'(z)=z.\tag{5}
$$
By symmetry $(4)$ and the optimality condition $(5)$, I now want to define a symmetric objective function $\tilde{J}(y)$, to which $(5)$ is a solution. How do I proceed? Normal integration obviously does not work.

Comment: Is the domain of $f$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}$? From the problem statement it seems it is $\mathbb{R}^2$ but from the solution it seems it is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo.

Comment: If you know the optimal point is obtained for $x = y$, then you can rewrite the problem as $\max_{z} \tilde{J}(z) = f(2z) - z^2$ and it will have the same optimality conditions.